# Importing a joomla plugin

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I have trouble importing my own plugin. I have tried numerous methods (e.g. JLoader and differnt variations of names to be imported), all of them failed.

This is the plugin's php content:

http://pastebin.com/mw7p52pV

This is its XML definition:

http://pastebin.com/mzcB0ejp

This is how I call it:

```
$res = JPluginHelper::importPlugin('Mycategory');
var_dump($res);

$results = $dispatcher->trigger( 'testMaxSizer', '');
var_dump($results);
```

Both var_dumps return either NULL or false.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try calling the plugin with 'maxsizer' instead of 'Mycategory'?

Comment: Where are you adding this code to? And are you sure you plugin is installed properly and enabled?

Comment: @Lodder: I'm a complete douche. Please add an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, so be sure you have properly installed the plugin and enabled it, else the trigger won't work

Comment: After installing the plugin for the 20th time, I finally forgot the one time the code was correct. Thanks